# How to get Capistrano 3 to use RVM ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

Gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano3-puma'
```

Deploy.rb:

```
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.1.1'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
```

Production.rb

```
namespace :rails do
  desc "Open the rails console on primary app server"
  task :console do
    on roles(:app), primary: true do
      execute_interactively "#{current_path}/script/rails console RAILS_ENV=production"
    end
  end

  def execute_interactively(command)
    cmd = "ssh -l deploy 255.255.255.255 -p 21 -t 'cd #{deploy_to}/current && #{command}'"
    info "Connecting to 255.255.255.255"
    exec cmd
  end
end
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'whenever/capistrano'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

When I run `cap production rvm:check` the output is:

```
rvm 1.25.19 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
system
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
```

Should it not be using `user` instead of `system` because I've specified the `rvm_type`?

When I run `cap production rails:console` then I get:

```
INFO Connecting to 255.255.255.255
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
Connection to 255.255.255.255 closed.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you understand how capistrano-rvm works.

[Here's the relevant code](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/blob/v0.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake#L38)

capistrano-rvm works by figuring out the location of your RVM installation, and then prefixing  your capistrano commands with the relevant [mapped commands](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map). The command-map is part of SSHKit.

Capistrano-rvm by default maps [gem rake ruby bundle](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/blob/v0.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake#L51) to an rvm-prefixed version. What this means is that whenever capistrano encounters a command, e.g. in the form of `execute :bundle` it will replace it with, e.g. `~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.1 do bundle`

You've completely side-stepped that entire mechanism in your contrived `execute_interactively` command that specifies the command in-line. In fact, you've completely side-stepped the beauty of capistrano as a whole by setting up your own SSH session!

Also the whole `set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }` is not at all needed, that's the reason you're using the capistrano-rvm gem.

---

As for why `cap production rvm:check` is displaying `system` is because the term `system` is overloaded in this case. What *you* think it means in this context is "what kind of rvm setup scheme is this, a `/usr/local/rvm` installation or a `~/.rvm` installation"

What it actually means is from [this code](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/blob/v0.1.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake#L9), i.e. it checks the ruby version that's listed in RVM as the *current ruby*, which the default installation of ruby on a server is known as the *system ruby*

Comment: Thanks, this answer made me go and investigate Cap3 a bit more. I've gotten to the point where my commands all work, but the console switches to inspect mode (https://gist.github.com/pawel2105/9706550)

Comment: "the relevant code" was a lifesaver!

If you take the path of install RVM in your own location rather than a default, you can tell the rvm capistrano plugin about it by putting this in your deploy.rb file: `set :rvm_custom_path, '/my/custom/path/to/rvm'`